# How to get all i18n messages in Play 2 with Java

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to retrieve all localized messages for a given locale in Play 2 Framework with Java? There seems to be API for Scala, but not for Java.

If there is no official API, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Don't know solution, but just curious what is target of this task (what for do you need it?)

Comment: i18n for angular.js - I want to keep both Play and Angular localizations in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Found nothing better then:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(play.Play.application().resourceAsStream("messages"));
    return ok(Json.toJson(prop)).as("application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Atually I'd ... separate them, I'd keep views/controller messages in common Play path but i18n file I prefer to keep in separate JS/JSON file.

Of course I don't know specification of your project but we have several hundreds of labels in project and only ~ 20 of them are for JS, so there's no reason to load something which won't be used ever.

On the other hand it's just *lighter* for Play to serve public static, then read it and converting to JSON each time.